# Como puedo hacer para que al hacer metodo post solo se agregue información en determinado objeto de la api? REACT, JSON, API, AXIOS

Tags: json, reactjs, api, axios

Estoy realizando mi primer proyecto en react y mi aplicación almacena las tareas diarias de un determinado usuario, para esto utilizo una api que se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es hacer un crud en el cual el usuario pueda agregar nuevas tareas, editarlas y eliminarla, pero no se como hacer para  que el método post solo afecte el objeto tasks, es decir que al añadir una nueva tarea se añada en ese array de objetos

este es mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al hacer el añadir tarea hace esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Gisell, por favor acostumbra a publicar el código fuente en formato de texto y no imágenes de este, lee [como hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ese `selectedItem` que debería guardar?

Comment: La nueva información creo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Antes que todo, la próxima vez que publiques una pregunta trata de
> incluir el código esencial utilizando las herramientas que ofrece
> *es.SO*, ***no incluir fotos de tu código*** ;)

Ahora, lo que nos convoca. Estabas bastante cerca de la solución, pero al momento de realizar la petición `Axios` estas enviando la tarea nueva sin asignarla al `state` correspondiente.

Te dejo el extracto del código que te serviría para obtener el resultado que quieres

```
const handleOnClick = (id, event) => {
    //event.preventDefault();

    setData((prev) => {
      return prev.map((item, idx) => {
        if (item.id === +id) {
          return { ...prev[idx], tasks: [...prev[idx].tasks, newTask] };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
    });
};
```

Básicamente lo que hace el método es setear el state **data** - q*ue es el que contiene la info que quieres desplegar* -, realizar un `map` para que recorra los objetos de dicho arreglo y *'matchear'* mediante la comparación del id del objeto, más el item seleccionado al que quieres agregar la nueva tarea.

**[Acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/update-nested-item-from-array-y9hsq?file=/src/App.js)** te dejo el link en *CodeSandbox* con el ejemplo completo; si tienes alguna duda acá estaremos :D

Nos comentas si te sirve!

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta! Así puse esta parte del código pero aun el método post no funciona, no se que estoy haciendo mal `const peticionPost = async (id, event) => {
    await axios.post(db, newTask)
      .then(response => {
        setData((prev) => {
          return prev.map((item, idx) => {
            if (item.id === +id) {
              return { ...prev[idx], tasks: [...prev[idx].tasks, newTask] };
            } else {
              return item;
            }
          });
        })
        setIsModalNewOpen(false)
      })
  }`

Comment: Es que no debes enviar newTask, debes enviar el objeto data completo; y en el then sólo recibes la respuesta que devuelve la API.